# How to run Huggingface BERT tokenizer in offline mode?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, huggingface-tokenizers

While running above code in my work laptop I'm getting the following error, but same error is not there when I run in my personal laptop. I wanted to check whether there is a way to fix this SSL error? Is there any way to run these code in offline mode by downloading the tokenizer from github repos https://github.com/huggingface/transformers ?

````
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
text = "Replace me by any text you'd like."
encoded_input = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='pt')
output = model(**encoded_input)```

*SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingface.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/models/bert-base-uncased (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))*
````

Answer (score 0):

According to this issue, https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/10379, you can export the variable `TRANSFORMERS_OFFLINE=1` and it should work (assuming you can get a connection at some point in time).

Add this to your code:

```
import os

os.environ['TRANSFORMERS_OFFLINE']="1"
```

You will need to be connected at least once for it to work, but it should cache it and work offline subsequently.